# Spring - get used TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have two transaction managers and was curious if there is some possibility to get the one that has been used.

To be more concrete, how could `underlyingMethod(..)` find out which transactionManager was used (without sending it an additional parameter "transactionManagerName/Ref"):

```
@Transactional("transactionManager1")
public void transactionFromFirstTM() {
    someClass.underlyingMethod()
}


@Transactional("transactionManager2")
public void transactionFromSecondTM() {
    someClass.underlyingMethod()
}
```

?

---

ok I have used this to get the hibernate Session from actual transaction manager:

```
protected Session getSession() {
    Map<Object, Object> resourceMap = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResourceMap();

    Session session = null;
    for (Object value : resourceMap.values()) {
        if (value instanceof SessionHolder) {
            session = ((SessionHolder) value).getSession();
            break;
        }
    }

    return session;
}
```

Comment: the original plan was to have two databases, and the proper one would be chosen simply by defining the linked transactionManager name in the Transactional annotation (the code behavior should be otherwise identical for both databases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, but you shouldn't do anything with the transaction manager. Some actions on the current transaction are available in [`TransactionSynchronizationManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html#getCurrentTransactionName%28%29)

Another useful class is the [`TransactionAspectUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectUtils.html). But not that both are meant to be used internally, and you should not rely on them in many places in your code.